# Iterative Counter, Daily Running Total of Weeks Hours

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

Excel VBA:

I'm struggling with the loop structure of an iterative counter to report running totals of hours worked per employee. Ex:

Day 1: 8 hrs worked, 8 hrs total
Day 2: 8 hrs worked, 16 hrs total
Day 3: 10 hrs worked, 26 hrs total
etc.

Currently, I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't loop through each value in the hrs range

```
Application.Intersect(cellRow, hrsRng)
```

Rather, it grabs the first reported hour value and runs that through the counter.  Rearranging the structure I can get the total weeks hours, but not the running total.

The fuller version tracks multiple employees across different phases of a project for pivot reporting, thus the additional "name" condition.  Running daily total rather than just weekly total is important due to when federal and CA overtime laws are triggered during the workweek.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Option Explicit
Function runTot(ByVal nm As String, nmRng As Range, dt As Range, dtRng As Range, hrsRng As Range, weekSt As String) As Double

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer 'iterative placeholder
    Dim cnt As Integer 'counter

    Dim callRng As Range 'Application.Caller row
    Dim wkStart As String 'sheet list validation to vb day

    Dim wkDateStart As Date 'week date start
    Dim wkDateEnd As Date 'week date end

    Dim dateVal As Date 'date, from Caller.Row.  used to find week bracketing dates

    Dim dateCell As Date 'loop date
    Dim hrsVal As Range 'loop hours
    Dim cellRow As Range 'cell row


    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Budget")

i = 0
cnt = 0

    Set callRng = ws.Range(Rows(Application.Caller.Row).Address)

    dateVal = Application.Intersect(callRng, dtRng).Value

    Select Case weekSt
        Case Is = "Sunday"
            wkStart = vbSunday
        Case Is = "Monday"
            wkStart = vbMonday
        Case Is = "Tuesday"
            wkStart = vbTuesday
        Case Is = "Wednesday"
            wkStart = vbWednesday
        Case Is = "Thursday"
            wkStart = vbThursday
        Case Is = "Friday"
            wkStart = vbFriday
        Case Is = "Saturday"
            wkStart = vbSaturday
    End Select

    'Sets Week Date Start and Week Date End, from Caller Date and day of the week
    Select Case Weekday(dateVal, wkStart)
        Case 1
            wkDateStart = dateVal
            wkDateEnd = DateAdd("d", 6, dateVal)
        Case 2
            wkDateStart = DateAdd("d", -1, dateVal)
            wkDateEnd = DateAdd("d", 5, dateVal)
        Case 3
            wkDateStart = DateAdd("d", -2, dateVal)
            wkDateEnd = DateAdd("d", 4, dateVal)
        Case 4
            wkDateStart = DateAdd("d", -3, dateVal)
            wkDateEnd = DateAdd("d", 3, dateVal)
        Case 5
            wkDateStart = DateAdd("d", -4, dateVal)
            wkDateEnd = DateAdd("d", 2, dateVal)
        Case 6
            wkDateStart = DateAdd("d", -5, dateVal)
            wkDateEnd = DateAdd("d", 1, dateVal)
        Case 7
            wkDateStart = DateAdd("d", -6, dateVal)
            wkDateEnd = dateVal
    End Select

    For Each cell In dtRng

        Set cellRow = ws.Range(Rows(cell.Row).Address)
        Set hrsVal = Application.Intersect(cellRow, hrsRng)
        dateCell = Application.Intersect(cellRow, dtRng).Value

            Do While cnt <= (dateVal - wkDateStart)
                If Application.Intersect(cellRow, nmRng) = nm Then
                    'Debug.Print hrsVal.Address & " " & hrsVal.Value
                    i = i + hrsVal.Value
                    runTot = i
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                End If
            Loop
    Next cell

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure why `cellRow` wouldn't iterate through the `Do While` loop, but I solved this in what's probably a simpler way; I completely ditched the `Do While` and added an If.

```
        For Each cell In dtRng

            Set cellRow = ws.Range(Rows(cell.Row).Address)
            Set hrsVal = Application.Intersect(cellRow, hrsRng)
            dateCell = Application.Intersect(cellRow, dtRng).Value

            If dateCell >= wkDateStart And dateCell <= dateVal Then
                i = i + hrsVal
                runTot = i
            End If
        Next cell
```